# Saving string to variable outside loop

Tags: python

```
test = "ABC"

for i in range(0, 5):
    print i
    test test.replace('ABC', str(i))

print test
```

This prints 0, whereas I expect it to print 4. What is going on?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? `roster` is empty, so there is nothing to replace.

Comment: You're calling `replace` on roster. What you're basically saying is: if `name` is in `roster`, then replace it with `'test'`'. But `roster` is empty so nothing ever happens.

Comment: You've completely changed the question after receiving answers. Please don't do that.

Comment: Do you mean test = test.replace('ABC',str(i)) ?

Comment: I agree Robert, you can't replace the integer index. But even so, why would you replace the string five times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This makes perfect sense.

`roster` is an empty string. The `replace` will never (assuming a `name_list` does not contain empty string, then I don't know how it will behave) match anything in an empty string.

Update:

It looks like, if your `name_list` contains an empty string, then it will do a replacement (Python 2.7):

```
''.replace('', 'foo') # => 'foo'
```

## Update since question *totally* changed.

(assuming you're missing an `=` between `test` and `test.replace('ABC', str(i))`)

Your question's new code, is expected to output `0`. You're mutating `test` to be `'0'`, then the match of `'ABC'` will never be satisfied again for values `1` through `4`.